# Replace token by value in mail

Tags: emails, tokens

I sent an email in a function.

My email body is like "Hello [user:name], blablablala --  Team [site:name]".

But the token aren't replace by their values in the email.

What's wrong ?

Cordially

Answer (score 1):

You need to run [token_replace](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7) on the email body and pass in the user object for the target user. In your function:
$global $user;

```
$emluser = user_load($user->uid);
$body = "Hello [user:name], blablablala -- Team [site:name]";
$body = token_replace($body, array('user' => $emluser));
```

You don't need to pass anything for the site tokens to be replaced.